# Does Lego increase a child's IQ?

Tags: intelligence

[The Sun](http://www.thesun.co.uk/sol/homepage/news/2831672/Playing-Lego-is-brain-booster-a-new-study-says.html) reports:

> PLAYING with Lego can make people BRAINIER, bosses claimed yesterday.
>   A study found that those who are experts with the toy building bricks are more agile with their hands and solve problems faster than the average person.

Can playing with some plastic pieces increase a child's IQ?

Comment: Does anyone have access to the Sun who can give just a little more context here? In particular, identifying features of the study, and whether it claimed causality or merely correlation.

Comment: And which caused which?  Correlation doesn't mean causation--it could simply be that those who are agile problem solvers are more likely to like Lego.

Comment: I do not know about the study in the Sun, and whether the claims were Lego-specific, but there is [a nice overview of studies on the effect of toy blocks on child development on Parenting Science](http://www.parentingscience.com/toy-blocks.html).